# S3 i9300 Soft Bricked. Heimdall says: Failed to receive handshake response. Result: -7

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, boot-loop, odin, heimdall

**I have**

- S3 i9300
- CWM working w/ cannot mount errors
- Download mode is fine
- It is stuck on Samsung i9300 logo

**What I have tried**

- Odin3 all version w/ pit file: fail
- Heimdall running on Ubuntu 64: fail

**Heimdal reports**

```
fabio@fabio-VirtualBox:/$ sudo heimdall print-pit --verbose --no-reboot
Heimdall v1.4.1

Copyright (c) 2010-2014 Benjamin Dobell, Glass Echidna
http://www.glassechidna.com.au/

This software is provided free of charge. Copying and redistribution is
encouraged.

If you appreciate this software and you would like to support future
development please consider donating:
http://www.glassechidna.com.au/donate/

Initialising connection...
Detecting device...
      Manufacturer: "SAMSUNG"
           Product: "Gadget Serial"

            length: 18
      device class: 2
               S/N: 0
           VID:PID: 04E8:685D
         bcdDevice: 021B
   iMan:iProd:iSer: 1:2:0
          nb confs: 1

interface[0].altsetting[0]: num endpoints = 1
   Class.SubClass.Protocol: 02.02.01
       endpoint[0].address: 83
           max packet size: 0010
          polling interval: 09

interface[1].altsetting[0]: num endpoints = 2
   Class.SubClass.Protocol: 0A.00.00
       endpoint[0].address: 81
           max packet size: 0200
          polling interval: 00
       endpoint[1].address: 02
           max packet size: 0200
          polling interval: 00
Claiming interface...
Setting up interface...

Initialising protocol...
Protocol initialisation successful.

Beginning session...

Some devices may take up to 2 minutes to respond.
Please be patient!

Session begun.

Downloading device's PIT file...
PIT file download successful.

Entry Count: 16
Unknown 1: 1598902083
Unknown 2: 844251476
Unknown 3: 30797
Unknown 4: 0
Unknown 5: 0
Unknown 6: 0
Unknown 7: 0
Unknown 8: 0


--- Entry #0 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 80
Attributes: 2 (STL Read-Only)
Update Attributes: 1 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 0
Partition Block Count: 1734
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: BOOTLOADER
Flash Filename: sboot.bin
FOTA Filename: 


--- Entry #1 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 81
Attributes: 5 (Read/Write)
Update Attributes: 1 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 1734
Partition Block Count: 312
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: TZSW
Flash Filename: tz.img
FOTA Filename: 


--- Entry #2 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 70
Attributes: 5 (Read/Write)
Update Attributes: 1 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 34
Partition Block Count: 16
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: PIT
Flash Filename: mx.pit
FOTA Filename: 


--- Entry #3 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 71
Attributes: 5 (Read/Write)
Update Attributes: 1 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 50
Partition Block Count: 2048
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: MD5HDR
Flash Filename: md5.img
FOTA Filename: 


--- Entry #4 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 1
Attributes: 5 (Read/Write)
Update Attributes: 1 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 8192
Partition Block Count: 8192
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: BOTA0
Flash Filename: -
FOTA Filename: 


--- Entry #5 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 2
Attributes: 5 (Read/Write)
Update Attributes: 1 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 16384
Partition Block Count: 8192
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: BOTA1
Flash Filename: -
FOTA Filename: 


--- Entry #6 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 3
Attributes: 5 (Read/Write)
Update Attributes: 5 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 24576
Partition Block Count: 40960
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: EFS
Flash Filename: efs.img
FOTA Filename: 


--- Entry #7 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 4
Attributes: 5 (Read/Write)
Update Attributes: 1 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 65536
Partition Block Count: 16384
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: PARAM
Flash Filename: param.bin
FOTA Filename: 


--- Entry #8 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 5
Attributes: 5 (Read/Write)
Update Attributes: 1 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 81920
Partition Block Count: 16384
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: BOOT
Flash Filename: boot.img
FOTA Filename: 


--- Entry #9 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 6
Attributes: 5 (Read/Write)
Update Attributes: 1 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 98304
Partition Block Count: 16384
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: RECOVERY
Flash Filename: recovery.img
FOTA Filename: 


--- Entry #10 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 7
Attributes: 5 (Read/Write)
Update Attributes: 1 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 114688
Partition Block Count: 65536
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: RADIO
Flash Filename: modem.bin
FOTA Filename: 


--- Entry #11 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 8
Attributes: 5 (Read/Write)
Update Attributes: 5 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 180224
Partition Block Count: 2097152
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: CACHE
Flash Filename: cache.img
FOTA Filename: 


--- Entry #12 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 9
Attributes: 5 (Read/Write)
Update Attributes: 5 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 2277376
Partition Block Count: 3145728
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: SYSTEM
Flash Filename: system.img
FOTA Filename: 


--- Entry #13 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 10
Attributes: 5 (Read/Write)
Update Attributes: 5 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 5423104
Partition Block Count: 1146880
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: HIDDEN
Flash Filename: hidden.img
FOTA Filename: 


--- Entry #14 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 11
Attributes: 5 (Read/Write)
Update Attributes: 1 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 6569984
Partition Block Count: 16384
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: OTA
Flash Filename: -
FOTA Filename: 


--- Entry #15 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 12
Attributes: 5 (Read/Write)
Update Attributes: 5 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 6586368
Partition Block Count: 0
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: USERDATA
Flash Filename: userdata.img
FOTA Filename: remained

Ending session...
Releasing device interface...
fabio@fabio-VirtualBox:/$ heimdall detect --verbose --usb-log-level debug
[timestamp] [threadID] facility level [function call] <message>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ 0.017617] [00000ebe] libusb: debug [libusb_get_device_list] 
[ 0.028439] [00000ebe] libusb: debug [libusb_get_device_descriptor] 
Device detected
[ 0.028512] [00000ebe] libusb: debug [libusb_exit] 
[ 0.028534] [00000ebe] libusb: debug [libusb_exit] destroying default context
```